# What does the word 「きりねえ」mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation, words, manga

Here is the sentence said by an old man who got only one eye visible.

教官先生...わしの目を見てくだせえ　たった一つっ**きりねえ**がなまじの肉親以上に本人のためを思っているこの目を！

In my opinion, he probably talked about his only visible one eye. If it means 'not only', I still have no idea how to use it in my translation below.

Is it a predicate to the noun 「たった一つ」?

If I'm correct, can I translate it like this,

Teachers, please look at my eye, I myself use it to looking for being more than his real parent regardless that I have only visible one left.

P.S. I translate the word　「なまじ」 as "regardless or thoughtlessly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious that it means "I have only one" here though it's technically a nonsensical phrase that mixes たった ひとつ きり（だが）with たった ひとつ きり しか ない. (きり is equivalent to だけ.)

なまじ means "half-way" or "not thoroughly".

- 本人の為を思っているこの目: this eye that thinks of his own benefit
- なまじの肉親以上に: more than his mere real parents
- たったひとつっきりないが * : though it's only one

Comment: I object to "technically a nonsensical phrase". It's a slightly obscure but perfectly respectable colloquial alternative to "shika nai", obviously related to the two usages of "kiri" you list but not just a malformed or erroneous version of either.